# How to directly set a vector's value with "many numbers" in the code in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

This question may seem awkward, since we can read the values for a vector (e.g., `a` below) from files outside, instead of in the code. Below is what I tried,but I suppose Fortran cannot contain so many characters in a line. Also, I am afraid the line cannot be separated into several lines "endlessly".

```
Program main
  implicit none
  REAL(8),dimension(1500)::a = (/, , , , ... ,/)
End program
```

The variable `a` has 1500 elements, and I want these values to directly be included in the code. So I do not use `read()` command. Do we need to separate this long line manually into several lines?

Comment: *Do we need to separate this long line manually into several lines?*  Yes.  Look around for Qs and As on the topic of *Fortran continuation lines*.

Comment: In the FORTRAN 95 standard, a maximum of 39 continuation lines are allowed. Maybe you can have 4 other variables (390 values each, 10 per line) then concatenate them into 'a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can write many short lines that write to a small section of the array.

Example:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(15)
  real(kind=rk),dimension(30)::a

  a(1:3) = [0.25733572697493723_rk, 0.03225738644740617_rk, 0.5414564639489547_rk]
  a(4:6) = [0.19327589136191725_rk, 0.49311615953762833_rk, 0.6433831692863491_rk]
  a(7:9) = [0.6859277892633444_rk, 0.641803334817996_rk, 0.2699446411426851_rk]
  a(10:12) = [0.3734332997800017_rk, 0.6383656815065594_rk, 0.6497673624736408_rk]
  a(13:15) = [0.698560401584833_rk, 0.8550812707577452_rk, 0.2429165361432739_rk]
  a(16:18) = [0.8083661742072051_rk, 0.21096311180256644_rk, 0.4482114317600794_rk]
  a(19:21) = [0.4254204225869541_rk, 0.30299480014092506_rk, 0.18464410073699633_rk]
  a(22:24) = [0.2020883904853492_rk, 0.793469769164798_rk, 0.010725578232863464_rk]
  a(25:27) = [0.597774960426935_rk, 0.23743374381177218_rk, 0.6515133874064444_rk]
  a(28:30) = [0.9372245495970037_rk, 0.22530033395862548_rk, 0.9991480087266069_rk]

end program
```

The example is deliberately shorter.